# Windows 8 - SQL Server 2008R2 - Set current user as admin

Tags: sql-server, windows-8, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having quite a problem with SQL Server.
When I installed it, my account was not an administrator, now it is. Apparently, since it was not an administrator of the machine, it is not an administrator of SQL Server, as a consequence I cannot create databases on my machine.

Now, I am on Windows 8, so it seems like SQL Server Configuration Manager is not as accesible as it was before, I managed to run it (I THINK!) from the MMC by running the following command: sqlservermanager10.msc.

Now, can anyone help me configure my current user as an SQL Server admin so I can create databases properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you want your account to have sysadmin rights on SQL Server. You can either do this via [SQL Server Management studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio), or the [SQLCMD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) command line utility. You don't use the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

**You need to login as an existing SA (or whichever the identity has the sysadmin role).**

## Using TSQL via SQLCMD

Run the following command (replacing domain\user with your details)

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [domain\user] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [domain\user]
GO
```

## Via the UI

In SQL Server Management Studio

Navigate to the Security node of the server, and R-Click & Select New Login

[image]

In the New Login dialog enter your domain user into the Window Authentication box

[image]

Then on the Right side select Server Roles and then make sure SysAdmin is selected

[image]

Then Ok that dialog and the windows account will have SA rights. This means then you can full administer the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear at all what's going on here, but it sounds to me like you haven't got any sysadmins if @Preet isn't correct.

The local Administrators group is not a member of the sysadmin role on recent versions of SQL Server (2005+, IIRC), and if I recall the installer complains if you try to configure it that way.  Instead, when you install the instance you specify the users or groups who will be granted the sysadmin role on the instance.

If you did not do this (I think it adds the account doing the installation by default) or used an account or group which was later deleted, had the SID changed, or some similar event, then you have an instance with no sysadmin logins that can authenticate.  You may be able to add one by switching the server to [single user mode](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/10/sql-server-start-sql-server-instance-in-single-user-mode/) or minimal configuration mode (`-f` instead of `-m`).

If none of that works, then you'll have to save your database files, nuke the instance, install the instance again, re-attach your database files, and go from there.

The only other thing I can think that it might be is that the instance is somehow running as a user account that doesn't have permissions to create files in the default database or log directory, but that seems highly unlikely.